# Is there a limit for Hope?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the anime, Percival was able to get the power from his 3 friends due to his magical power Hope. Can he get in the same way the power of thousands or millions, kind like the Genki Dama in Dragon Ball, or is there a limit for it?